# Encoding and assigning the result to a label

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to do some encoding and then assign the result to a label. Is there a more optimal (or concise) way to write this?

```
// encoding fix    
NSString *correctStringTitle = [NSString stringWithCString: [[item objectForKey:@"main_tag"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] 
                                                  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

cell.titleLabel.text = [correctStringTitle capitalizedString];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a marginally more concise solution:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithCString:[[item[@"main_tag"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].capitalizedString;
```

If I had to do this more than once I would consider hiding this complexity in an NSString category like:

```
@interface NSString(Utils)
    -(NSString)stringWithLatinEncoding;
@end

@implementation NSString(Utils)

-(NSString)stringWithLatinEncoding
{
     return [NSString stringWithCString:[self cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

This will simplify your code to:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = ((NSString*)item[@"main_tag"]).stringWithLatinEncoding.capitalizedString;
```